# "'System.StackOverflowException" in "OnEndPage" event handler

Tags: c#, itext

In the code below, you can see that I overrode `OnEndPage` event and tried to add a paragraph to the document. However, I get an "System.StackOverflowException" error when attempting to run the code.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it?

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Paragraph");
    document.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: Do you get a stack trace? Does adding a paragraph to the document cause `OnEndPage` to be called again?

Comment: can you remove the call to `Add`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you are adding the paragraph in the onEnd, when you add the paragraph to the doc it must be rewritten, so it calls again onEnd, then you add the paragraph and OnEnd is called and...

Comment: Nope, can't get a stack trace. And yeah, it seems that onEnd keeps getting called over and over again.

Comment: I think you would use a `try { } catch { }` and read the Stack Trace of the exception. It would help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **forbidden** to use `document.Add()` in a page event. The `document` object passed as a parameter is actually a `PdfDocument` object. You should use it for read-only purposes only. This is documented in my book [iText in Action - Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book).

If you want to add content in the `OnEndPage` method, you need the `writer`, for instance `writer.DirectContent`.